# PHP excel weird characters

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I'm using the basic phpexcel 01simple-download-xlsx.php as Is
Didnt add any code of my own for now .. 
And I get unexpected results

```
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");
    // Add some data
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
                ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
                ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');
    // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
                ->setCellValue('A5', 'hello');
    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

And this is what i get
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzkSR.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some other characters were printed before my function